# JS an event after all the html is loaded

Tags: javascript

I want to make something like library in JS. If table has a class="aClass" I want to automatically modify some of it's elements using JS.

I tried this way:

```
window.onLoad = LoadSetup();

function LoadSetup()
{
  tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
  alert(tables.length);  // it's 0 though there are is one in the document
}
```

But i seems that this function runs before loading html. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `onload` needs to be all lower case.  Rather than binding an event handler to `window.onload`, you are adding a custom property to `window` of `onLoad`.
2. Assign `onload` a *reference* to the function. Omit the parentheses.  With the parens, you are calling the function immediately, and assigning its return value to `window.onLoad`.

Try this:

```
window.onload = LoadSetup;
```

Comment: You are right, thanks. It was hard to track for me (2 days of experience with JS :) ) as it actually did some action more or less what I expected and when I expected. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
LoadSetup();
});
```

from JQuery: http://jquery.com/

Regards,

Comment: jQuery is a tool that is great when it is needed. Plain old javascript will more than do the trick here..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
window.onload = LoadSetup;
```

Including the parenthesis will execute the function and set window.onload to the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the result of the function `LoadSetup`. Assign the reference `LoadSetup` instead:

```
window.onload = LoadSetup;
```

Also note it's `window.onload` (case sensitive).